# Can a defect be locked, to prevent task creation?

Tags: rally

Is it possible to intentionally lock a Rally defect in such a way that users are not able to create tasks for the defect?

Our metrics collection tools are working off Rally stories.  Our process for defects is supposed to be, the user creates a task or tasks under the original story which spawned the defect.

Unfortunately, not all the team members remember/follow the process.  We end up with tasks associated directly to the defect which don't get reported on in our metric data pulls.

I suppose I could rewrite the metric data pull apps, but as a quick fix I am looking to just prevent the creation of tasks on defects.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Rally permissions model is not that granular. Tighter control over the permissions model is a popular feature request. I'd encourage you to vote on the following:

[More granular user permissions](http://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D391)

Idea at [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com)

To garner votes and visibility for this enhancement request.